# Why does Azure Auto-Scale scale go lower then minimum amount of instances?

Tags: azure, autoscaling

This picture should show it all:

[image]

As you can see the minimum instance is set on three, but autoscale decides to first scale up, and than scale back down again - *below* the minimum.

I guess even if the CPU is far below the target I assume it should never go below the minimum. Why is this happening? Do I need to set somewhere else a setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops. Apparently I had set up a day / night time schedule, and at this certain point it went to the night time schedule where it was min/max 1 instance.